# Constant resistance mode in electronic load

Tags: resistance, multimeter, testing, test-equipment, electronic-load

I have this [DC electronic load.](https://www.bkprecision.com/products/dc-electronic-loads/8540-150-w-dc-electronic-load.html)

I am setting this electronic load to a constant resistance mode option  - say 100 ohms - and turning the output ON.

When I measure the resistance across the electronic load terminals using a multimeter, I am not able to read the value as 100 ohms. I am getting high resistance values and it is showing as open circuit.

However, if I connect a power supply to the electronic load and ask it to consume a current equivalent of 100 ohms, the electronic load is consuming the required current from the power supply as if it was connected to a 100 ohm resistance across it.

- Power supply was set to 10V.
- DC constant resistance was set to 100 ohms.
- Current consumption to the power supply was 100mA.

So, actually, the electronic load seems to be setting a constant resistance of 100 ohms when I set it as such, but I am not able to measure using the multimeter. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual:

https://bkpmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/manuals/en-us/8540_manual.pdf

You need at least 1mA of input current for proper operation.  Your DVM does not supply that much for resistance measurements.

Page 19:

[image]

How much current does your voltmeter supply?  It's not readily found.  However, I tried a simple setup here, and this is what I got for a 100 ohm resistor (0.3 mA):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So, you're saying that the input terminals of the DC Load would require atleast 1mA so as to read 100Ohms (which I have set) in the multimeter? And https://www.fluke.com/en-in/product/electrical-testing/digital-multimeters/fluke-179 - This is the multimeter which I am using. How much current will it provide?

Comment: Edited the answer above indicating that my meter is about 0.3 mA in resistance mode for 100 ohm load.  YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify the first question in my comment

Comment: **Disclaimer: I do not own, and have never operated this unit.**  An electronic load  (EL) is not a _passive_ load. It's understandable that it would require some amount of drive signal in order to operate as a programmed resistance. It appears that your EL requires that the signal applied to its inputs to be able to deliver a 1 mA signal (minimum) for operation.

Answer (score 1):

The electronic load would do something like read the voltage at the output and draw a constant current based on a calculation of that voltage * 1/Rset.

Your multimeter provides, by design, only a tiny current, which is too low for the circuitry in the electronic load to read accurately. There should be some indication of the resolution of voltage/current measurement in the datasheet or manual.

Comment: https://www.fluke.com/en-in/product/electrical-testing/digital-multimeters/fluke-179 - This is the multimeter which I am using. Could you please tell how much current will it provide? Where to see it